# Not all named parameters have been set: [:timestamp::date]

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

Here is my code:

```
public static List<Bean> getDate(int id){
    Session session = DatabaseSession.getInstance();

    List<Bean> cmts = session.createSQLQuery(
                              "select datecommented::timestamp::date from commenttable 
                                     where id = "+id
                              ).list();
    session.close();

    return cmts;
}
```

I get this error:

> Not all named parameters have been set: [:timestamp::date] [select datecommented::timestamp::date from commenttable where id = 312]

I want to know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can help us help you by formatting your code so we do not have to scroll it.

Comment: in hibernate anything after colon : is considered as Named Parameter so you are getting this error , You need to change datecommented::timestamp::date line

Answer (score 1):

```
Try using escape character : eg-    yourtime:: time

replace it by yourtime \\:\\: time
In my case above trick work...

public static List<Bean> getDate(int id){
    Session session = DatabaseSession.getInstance();

    List<Bean> cmts = session.createSQLQuery("select datecommented\\:\\:timestamp\\:\\:date from commenttable where id = "+id).list();
    session.close();

    return cmts;
}
```